# How to download spring framework zip file

Tags: spring, download

I am trying to download spring framework 3.2.4 zip file from www.springsource.org/download/community. It is redirecting me to http://spring.io/projects. From there I went in to Spring framework and checked for zip file but there is no zip file to download. I tried to google but there were some old instructions which were easy to download. Looks like some thing got changed in the way we download zip file. 
please help me with instructions to download.