# Spring : Bean class is not recognised by the spring and throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring framework and trying out a simple example of the same.

I have a bean class called 'Triangle' in my com.xyz.model package and one main class called DrawingApp in my com.xyz.DrawingApp package.

**Here is my spring.xml config file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="triangle" class="com.xyz.model.Triangle">
</bean>

</beans>
```

**Triangle.java**

```
package com.xyz.model;

public class Triangle {
public void draw() {
    System.out.println("Triangle drawn");
}
}
```

**DrawingApp.java**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
Triangle triangle = (Triangle)context.getBean("triangle");
triangle.draw();
```

**I have included these jars :**

```
org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar

commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3-javadoc.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3-sources.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3-tests.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3-test-sources.jar
commons-logging-adapters-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-tests.jar
```

**My class and xml file position position is :**

```
Triangle class is in this path -- com.xyz.model - SpringBeanFactory/src
DrawingApp class is in this path -- com.xyz.DrawingApp - SpringBeanFactory/src
spring.xml - SpringBeanFactory/src
```

**I am getting this exception :**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.xyz.model.Triangle] for bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.model.Triangle
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:590)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.fulcum.DrawingApp.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.model.Triangle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 9 more
```

Can somebody guide me to solve my problem ?

Comment: Sorry..i did not put my exception previously..now edited the question..pleas have a look.

Comment: How are you compiling and running your program? Your `Triangle` class is not on the class path.

Comment: Have you placed your `spring.xml` inside src folder, not in any other?

Comment: Yes..its path is this (spring.xml - SpringBeanFactory/src)

Comment: Replace this piece of code in your spring.xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://WWW.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">


<beans>
 <bean id="triangle" class="com.xyz.model.Triangle">
 </bean>
</beans>` let me know the result.!

Comment: Did you try `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring.xml");` like this ?

Answer (score 0):

@xyz : replace this piece of code in your spring.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



    <bean id="triangle" class="com.xyz.model.Triangle">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

then let me know the result.

Comment: NO luck..still throwing the exception :(

Comment: Yes I tried what all you suggested..still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The **project structure** would be looks like

[image]

**DrawingApp.java:**

```
package com.xyz.DrawingApp;   

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.xyz.model.Triangle;

public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();
    }

}
```

**Triangle.java:**

```
package com.xyz.model;

public class Triangle {

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println(" Triangle drawn.");
    }

}
```

**spring.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" 
         "http://WWW.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

    <beans>
        <bean id="triangle" class="com.xyz.model.Triangle" />
    </beans>
```

It works good.

Comment: Run your project from `DrawingApp.java` file.

Comment: hey everything is same..But still why is it not running? can it be the problem due to jar files? Can you please share the jar files or the link from which you have downloaded it?

Comment: You can find all [spring jar file at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124445/how-to-download-spring-framework-zip-file/21302118#21302118). There you can see my answer.

Comment: Have you imported `Triangle class` in `DrawingApp class`..?

Comment: I am doing it in eclipse ..so it will get imported automatically

Comment: that's it., no issue.. have you tried with jar files?

Comment: not yet :( I downloaded it ..extracted the files and from downloads/spring folder I used all jars that is in libs folder removing all my previous jars..and with that I run program then it gave logFactory exception ..so I included common-loging jars that i have mentioned above..And it then gave my old excetion..ClassNotFound :(

Comment: Are you there? Can it be version compatiblity problem? common-logging version is 1.1.3 and spring jar files version is 4.0.1?If it can be so can you please let me know proper version for common-logging?

Comment: commons-loggin 1.1.3 & spring 3.x.

Comment: I downloaded 3.2.7 version and used it in my class path..still not working ..could it be eclipse version issue? :(

Comment: which version of eclipse you are using??

Comment: How you have added your jar files??

Comment: yes..i added 1.1.3 version of common-logging jar and 3.2.7 version of spring jar..not working yet..i am using eclipse kepler version.

Comment: How you have added your jar files?? Either in `User Library` or some other way??

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same problem with pretty much the exact same code (Java Brains??), but I remembered that I mis-spelled the class name Triangle so I refactored it to the correct spelling and ran into your problem.

I ditched the whole thing and rebuilt the project from scratch and this time it worked.

It may have something to so with the classfiles being corrupted, so you might try deleting everything in the bin folder and try running again.