# Canot Download Spring MVC jar files from spring official website

Tags: spring, url, spring-mvc, download

I am facing this issue since months. My aim is to download the spring mvc jar files so i visited the official link [Spring Project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) . On the page you can see the option to download the spring framework based on the versions available , but the download link is not working.

Comment: No there isn't a download link, there is only the ability to use Maven or Gradle (or ivy) to get the jars. You shouldn't be hunting the internet for jars you need let a dependency manager do that for you.

Comment: can you give an example for how to get the jars using dependency manager?

Comment: That is on the website you link to. The dependencies are given for maven or gradle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download spring framework zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124445/how-to-download-spring-framework-zip-file)

Answer (score 1):

Following link you can use to download spring release in which you are interested.

http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/

Answer (score 0):

I thank M.Deinum for pointing this out. One cannot directly download the jar files, instead will need to use dependency manager live maven etc.